# OpenCV installation on windows

Tags: windows, opencv, installation

I'm trying to install OpenCV on Windows and I followed the [Installation by Using git-bash (version>=2.14.1) and cmake (version >=3.9.1)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html) tutorial from the official OpenCV documentation but when I run the build operation I get an error.

I'm using:

- Windows 10
- CMake 3.9.1
- Git Bash 2.17.0
- TDM64 GCC compiler 5.1.0

Here's the [error](https://pastebin.com/eiv6msk1)

```
In file included from C:\lib\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp:59:0:
C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/mfplay.h:77:50: error: 'MFP_MEDIAITEM_CHARACTERISTICS' has not been declared
     STDMETHOD_(HRESULT,GetCharacteristics)(THIS_ MFP_MEDIAITEM_CHARACTERISTICS *pCharacteristics) PURE;
                                                  ^
C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/mfplay.h:79:46: error: 'IMFPMediaPlayer' has not been declared
     STDMETHOD_(HRESULT,GetMediaPlayer)(THIS_ IMFPMediaPlayer **ppMediaPlayer) PURE;
```

Did someone encounter this kind of error?

Answer (score 3):

Yes I also encountered this error (when compiling with MinGW-w64 gcc 8.1).

For you and anybody else who finds this question when this error occurs (like me), here's what solved the issue for me:

When not using Visual Studio, you have to disable some features which are not supported. Build with cmake options WITH_IPP=OFF and WITH_MSMF=OFF

Solution found on opencv answers: http://answers.opencv.org/question/192758/compile-error-when-compiling-for-windows-341-dev/